# Who of Aizen's Arrancar were Vasto Lorde?

Tags: bleach

When Harribel is killed, during her flashback Apacci comments saying that Harribel was a Vasto Lorde.

So I am wondering who of Aizen's Arrancar were Vasto Lorde

Answer (score 2):

It was implied that top 4 of the Espada were all Vasto Lorde level as they were far superior combatwise than a Soul Society Captain. However, out of the four, only Tier Harribel was confirmed as a Vasto Lorde.

Comment: There's an official side story thingie that shows how Ulquiorra becomes a Vasto Lorde.

Comment: I don't think that Stark and Barragan were just Adjuchas.
And we still don't know if Grimmjow was able to become a Vasto Lorde after eating his companions.

Comment: Barragan looks like a Vasto Lorde to me. When Aizen went to subdue the so called "Lord of Hueco Mundo", it was shown that Barragan was as humano-like as he can be, considering that his power is that of "time", which is different than Grimmjow. Grimmjow was shown as a panther.